# How do I remove first line from text and only the first?

Tags: mysql

I have a tables "Table1"  in this table I have a Text NOT null field - "value". the value field is populated like so:

> value: 1.2.3.4 [cookie] : butter - 1 cup.
>
> 1.2.3.4 [cookie] : flour - 2 cup.
>
> 1.2.3.4 [cookie] : sugar - 1/2 cup.

I need to remove only the FIRST line and keep all others. This value can grown up to 500 lines. I am unsure how to delete only the

1.2.3.4 [cookie] : butter - 1 cup.

line.

I tried using replace and substring_index without success. This was my attempt:

```
SELECT name, SUBSTRING_INDEX(value, '\n', 1) FROM variables
```

which returns:

Cookies|  1.2.3.4 [cookie] : butter - 1 cup.

The values are put in with new lines as the "separator". I am looking to replace the values with everything after the first string of character up to the end of the first "line". This is more of of a block of text that I need to adjust.

Please assist in removing only the first line for the value.

Comment: What makes that line 'first'? Alphabetic order? An ID column of some sort? Other choices??

Comment: In a relational database, there is no such thing as the **first** line! On what basis are you deciding that "1.2.3.4 [cookie] : butter - 1 cup" is the first line? By datetime_of_insertion? By `PRIMARY KEY`? How are you determining first? Also, to remove a "line" - i.e. record, you need to use `DELETE`.

Comment: Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.

Comment: I think the point is that this is a single text field. So the comments about "what is the first line" are missing that point.

This is a question about string manipulation - how to extract the first line from a string (up to the newline character)

Answer (score 1):

You're almost there. I think what you need is:

```
SELECT substring(value, LOCATE('\n', value)+1)
```

This means:

- find the first newline in the string
- then add one (to go to the next character after the newline)
- and return everything from that position to the end of the string

Answer (score 0):

It's kinda hard to tell from your question & example you provided; you say you want to update but your example shows a select. You also don't mention version of mysql you're using.

However, based on what you said you wanted & the substring_index you've used, you can use:

```
    UPDATE Table1
    SET Value = REPLACE(value,
    SUBSTRING_INDEX(value, '\n', 1),'');
```

to replace everything up to the first found newline with nothing.

This is straight from http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-string-replace-function.aspx

I'm not a regular user of mysql, but a quick google search for mysql string functions turned up this tutorial.